# How i can retrieve data using eloquent model inversely

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel 6x for developing school management project, So i have `Student` and `Class_room` models with many to many relationship and having pivot table `class_room_student`.
The question is, i want to retrieve student class name by using

`Student::find(1)->class_rooms()->first()->name.` 
But it not work for me it show me the following error

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in Psy Shell code on line 1.

However i can fetch students by class like `Class_room::find(1)->students()->first()->name`.
I need to fix this problem...Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you said you defined many to many relationship between student and class room models. In collections ,you can get data into array or json and then you have iterate each record.

My advise to you that please define one to many relationships between School and Classrooms.

Then you can get data from your query.

Comment: But one student can refer to different classes. for example student got admission in class one after the exam the he goes to next class class two. So in this case one student can be in many classes and any class have many students. Isn't this?

Comment: But any way i have solve my problem by changing the model name to Croom. There was problem in model name have multiple words. Thank you